# Other languages not rendering in Rich Text content control when exporting to PDF using ASPOSE.WORDS for .NET

Tags: asp.net, richtextbox, aspose.words

I have some `HTML encoded Russian text` that have been assigned to a Rich text content control.

When exporting the document to `.DOC`, it exports perfectly displaying the Russian fonts.

But, when exporting to `.PDF`, it exports the Russian fonts as garbage `text`.

Please help.

This is the string assigned to the Rich text content control.

```
string innerText = @"<html><meta charset='UTF-8'><head></head><body>&lt;span style=&quot;font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; color: #003366; font-size: 11px;&quot;&gt;ыва фыв фыв фвввввв фцу фвф в&lt;/span&gt;</body></html>";
```

Comment: Can you post the link of sample document and code? I tried at my end with the latest version and the PDF shows the same text, no garbage.

Comment: Saqib, The problem was resolved when I used the Aspose.dll version 15.1. Earlier I was using Aspose.dll version 14.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved when I used the Aspose.dll version 15.1. Earlier I was using Aspose.dll version 14.6